# RequestMapping for Urls that are decided on startup

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a case or I want to have a specific controller to handle request patterns that are decided by a field in another class, it is similar to have the pattern coming from a resources property but instead of using ${propertyName} it will be the return type of the method:

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {
    private final urlDecider;

    @RequestMapping(urlDecider.getPatterns())
    public String handle(HttpServletREquest request) {}
}
```

`HandlerAdapter` seems to be similar to what I want but the problem is that the supports method parameter are only have handler as a parameter and not also the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking at DispatcherServlet HandlerMapping and its derivatives seemed to be what I was looking for:

```
public class CustomHandlerMapping extends AbstractUrlHandlerMapping {
    @Override
    protected Object lookupHandler(String urlPath, HttpServletRequest request) {
        final List<String> patterns = urlDecider.getPatterns();
        final PathMatcher pathMatcher = getPathMatcher();
        final boolean anyMatch = patterns.stream()
            .anyMatch(pattern -> pathMatcher.match(pattern, urlPath));
        return anyMatch ? someController : null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SpEL can be used to do that. The following was tested on Spring Boot 2 / Spring 5.0.9. This example calls a method on the same bean to get the endpoint name but you can replace the bean and method names in the SpEL expression to whatever works for your application.

```
@Slf4j
@RestController("testBean")
public class TestBean {

  public String endpoint() {
    return "/test";
  }

  @RequestMapping("#{testBean.endpoint()}")
  public void doit() {
    log.info("Hello World");
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an old project using spring mvc, I tried this solution and it didn't work for me, might be because in my example urlDecider is a bean that is injected into the controller, I managed to solve this using a HandlerMapping

Comment: @Shadi It might be because your old project uses a version of spring MVC that doesn't support SPEL in the `@RequestMapping`. I _think_ it was added quite recently. Anyway, I'm glad you got it working.